# R: Best approach for categorizing rows based on tricky conditions on column values?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, case-when

I've been trying so hard to find answers to my question, but to no avail. I'd really appreciate your help!

I have a dataset with multiple columns that have categorical values (1-6). They also contain many missing values (NA). I'm trying to create a new column that categorizes each row value based on these column values. I have many conditions (40+) relating to 5 columns. Some of the conditions are:

1. col1 = 1, col2 = NA or 1
2. col1 = 1, col3 = 1, col4 = NA
3. col1 = 1, col2 = 4, col5 = 4

and I want all the other rows that do not meet one of the conditions to be categorized as 0 while the rows that meet one of the conditions to be 1.

So far I've tried:

```
col1<- c(1,NA,6,4,2,1)
col2<- c(NA,4,2,NA,5,4)
col3<- c(NA,5,3,2,1,6)
col4<- c(1,2,3,2,NA,6)
col5<- c(5,6,NA,2,1,4)
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
df

df <- df %>%
  mutate(new = case_when(
    col1 == 1 & (is.na(col2)|col2 == 1) ~ 1,
    (col1&col3 == 1) & is.na(col4) ~ 1,  
    col1 == 1 & (col2&col5) == 4 ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0))
```

However, it clearly does not work. What would be the best way to categorize the rows based on the column values? I would like the output of a new column containing 0s and 1s depending on the conditions. Thank you so much for your time and expertise in advance!

Comment: try adding `rowwise` `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate...`

Answer (score 1):

I would try to write a small helper function that takes the logic of the code.
For example like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

col1 <- c(1, NA, 6, 4, 2, 1)
col2 <- c(NA, 4, 2, NA, 5, 4)
col3 <- c(NA, 5, 3, 2, 1, 6)
col4 <- c(1, 2, 3, 2, NA, 6)
col5 <- c(5, 6, NA, 2, 1, 4)


df <- tibble(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    NA    NA     1     5
#> 2    NA     4     5     2     6
#> 3     6     2     3     3    NA
#> 4     4    NA     2     2     2
#> 5     2     5     1    NA     1
#> 6     1     4     6     6     4

eval_func <- function(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) {
  r1 <- c1 == 1 & (is.na(c2) | c2 == 1)
  r2 <- (c1 == 1 & c3 == 1) & is.na(c4)
  r3 <- c1 == 1 & (c2 == 4 & c5 == 4)
  res <- r1 | r2 | r3
  as.integer(res) # convert to 0 1
}

df %>%
  mutate(new = eval_func(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5   new
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1    NA    NA     1     5     1
#> 2    NA     4     5     2     6     0
#> 3     6     2     3     3    NA     0
#> 4     4    NA     2     2     2     0
#> 5     2     5     1    NA     1     0
#> 6     1     4     6     6     4     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could first create a new row where all the values are "0".

```
df%>%
          mutate("new" = 0)
```

Then you go with your case_when conditions and let insert the "1" on the right place.

```
df <- df %>%
          mutate("new" = case_when(
                    col1 == 1 & (is.na(col2)|col2 == 1) ~ 1,
                    (col1&col3 == 1) & is.na(col4) ~ 1,  
                    col1 == 1 & (col2&col5) == 4 ~ 1,
                    TRUE ~ 0))
```

[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajCDC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't write your formulas like `(col1 & col3 == 1)`.
You should write them independently as `(col1 == 1 & col3 == 1)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~col1, ~col2, ~col3, ~col4, ~col5,
  1,    NA,    NA,     1,     5,
  NA,     4,     5,     2,     6,
  6,     2,     3,     3,    NA,
  4,    NA,     2,     2,     2,
  2,     5,     1,    NA,     1,
  1,     4,     6,     6,     4
)
df %>%
  mutate(new = case_when(
    col1 == 1 & (is.na(col2) | col2 == 1) ~ 1,
    col1 == 1 & col3 == 1 & is.na(col4) ~ 1,  
    col1 == 1 & col2 == 4 & col5 == 4 ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5   new
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    NA    NA     1     5     1
#> 2    NA     4     5     2     6     0
#> 3     6     2     3     3    NA     0
#> 4     4    NA     2     2     2     0
#> 5     2     5     1    NA     1     0
#> 6     1     4     6     6     4     1
```